# Change keyboard layout for Vim's command mode to English after it defaults to using Swedish keyboard layout

Tags: vim, keyboard-layout

I'm using GVim and it defaults to using a Swedish keyboard layout. Is there some way of changing that to an English one?

I don't have access to `setxkbmap` on this system, for some odd reason. So I don't think I could do it on an OS level. I don't care whether it stays English when I'm in insert mode or not, but I really need it to be English for command mode.

Comment: Gvim menu: Edit > Keyboard Layout helps?

Answer (score 1):

Option [`keymap`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27keymap%27) allows changing the meaning of keys on insert mode, while [`langmap`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27langmap%27) does the same in normal and visual mode.

Note that these options requires Vim compiled with `+keymap` and `+langmap`. You can check if they are available on your Vim with command `:version`.

Another option is using another external layout switcher, as `xkb-switch`. There is a vim plugin that may be used to access it:

- [`vim-xkbswitch`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4503) Automatic keyboard layout switcher.

I don't know about Swedish keyboard, but this plugin may also be useful:

- [`translit3`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3056): Plugin used for text transliteration.

Last, additional information can be found on [this answer to a similar question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8152137/717124).